# Displaying additional data based on aggregate results

Tags: sql, count, aggregate, sql-server-2014

this is my first question and I didn't really know what search criteria to use.

Anyway, I have the query below to show which accountIDs are duplicated in a table and how many times.  Also in this table are other fields such as firstName, lastname, dob, etc.  I want to be able to display this data based on the results from this query.  Any help for a SQL novice is appreciated, thanks!

```
SELECT accountid, COUNT(AccountId) as Count
from accounts
where RelationshipCode = 'SB'
group by AccountId
HAVING COUNT(AccountId)>1 
order by AccountId
```

Comment: Have you tried to just add them to the select part?

Comment: Are firstName, lastname, dob, etc. always the same for an accountid? If so, simply add those columns to select list and to group by clause.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, ...? You should always tag the DBMS when asking SQL questions. SQL dialects differ, and what works for one DBMS may not work for another.

Comment: jarlh, no those values are going to be different in most cases.

Comment: Jan, adding them to the select would work if firstname, lastname, etc were also the same

Answer (score 0):

```
select acc.*,
       sub.count
from account acc
     inner join (SELECT accountid, COUNT(AccountId) as Count
                 from accounts
                 where RelationshipCode = 'SB'
                 group by AccountId
                 HAVING COUNT(AccountId)>1) sub on sub.accountid=acc.accountid
order by acc.AccountId
```

Like this? Get all accounts which are duplicated?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT accountid, firstName, lastname,dob,  COUNT(*) as Count  `  
FROM accounts  `  
WHERE RelationshipCode = 'SB'  `  
GROUP BY AccountId,firstName, lastname,dob  `  
HAVING COUNT(*)>1   `  
ORDER BY AccountId`
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this, but this would only work if the firstname , lastname and dob were also all the same (which I failed to explain are not)

Answer (score 0):

An accounts table with duplicate account IDs? Oops, how much worth is the ID then? You are doing right to look for duplicates. Delete them and make the ID unique (probably by making it the table's primary key).

Your query already gets the account IDs in question, so you could use them to select from the table again:

```
select *
from accounts
where accountid in
( 
  select accountid
  from accounts
  where relationshipcode = 'SB'
  group by accountid
  having count(*) > 1 
)
order by accountid;
```

An alternative is to use the analytic version of `COUNT`, so as to have to read the table only once:

```
select *
from
(
  select accounts.*, count(*) over (partition by accountid) as cnt
  from accounts
  where relationshipcode = 'SB'
) counted
where cnt > 1
order by accountid;
```